# Connecting to Kerberos server using Java

Tags: java, kerberos

i am working on a java code that would retrieve ticket(TGT) from kerberos server.I have installed my kerberos server on a linux machine and have created principal's as well. Now i am trying to connect to this kerberos server using java code from my Windows machine. Please let me know of any code or resource available to do this?

I have tried following resources (http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jgss/tutorials/AcnOnly.html) but got no success,since i am not aware how to configure the config file. Any help is appreciated

the jaas.conf provided in the resource i have mentioned contains following details. Is this good enough or should i be adding anymore details

```
/** Login Configuration for the JaasAcn and
 ** JaasAzn Applications 
 **/

JaasSample {
   com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required;
};
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what you're looking for?  The resource you point at is a good one; for example specific help with config file would be easier to give than this general question

Comment: Yes, please elaborate.

Comment: Your jaas conf is one of the most minimalist i have seen in my life. It will take all the defaults com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule will assume. What kind of authentication do you want exactly. And please post code that you have written